# Ember AppKit and embedded object using ember data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

I'm trying to create a model having embedded data using Ember AppKit and the ES6 syntax but I'm a bit confused.

I found this article explaining the way to embedded data into a model:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration

But I don't know how to apply this to my scope. I should add the "map" into the adapter to specify that my attribute will be embedded, but I don't know how.

This is what I have:

**adapters/item.js**

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'path/to/api/json'
});
```

How to add the map here??

**models/item.js**

```
var attr = DS.attr,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr('string')
    width: belongsTo('valueUnit'),
    height: belongsTo('valueUnit'),
    weight: belongsTo('valueUnit')
});
```

I think here it should look something like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr('string')
    width: belongsTo('valueUnit', {embedded: 'always'}),
    height: belongsTo('valueUnit', {embedded: 'always'}),
    weight: belongsTo('valueUnit', {embedded: 'always'})
});
```

**models/value-unit.js**

```
var attr = DS.attr;

export default DS.Model.extend({
    value: attr('number')
    unit: attr('string')
});
```

And this is what I get from the server:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "123456789",
      "width": {
        "value": 150,
        "unit": "m"
      },
      "height": {
        "value": 5.3,
        "unit": "ft"
      },
      "weight": {
        "value": 12,
        "unit": "lb"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this is just a sample problem, but there is no need to treat valueUnit as a model. That will bring a lot of overhead and complexity. It's not a model--it's just a complex datatype. If you want more control over it or help getting to and fro, you can define a transform so you can define it as `width: DS.attr('valueUnit')`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a serializer for item model. Here is the [guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#embedded-records) on how to write the serializer.

(In your case, you are extracting the data from items array. So implement the extractArray function.)

Hope it helps!